# Aplicacion JAVA web, hacerla totalmente portable

Tags: java, http

Hola que tal? tengo una aplicación JAVA que hace de servidor HTTP, y lo que me gustaría hacer es, agregar todos los archivos FRONT-END de la aplicación en el mismo jar, y cuando transporto el archivo jar, se puedan escribir en la misma ubicación de donde se encuentra los archivos de la pagina para así al solicitar estos archivos estén presente en el disco rígido, por ejemplo:
Tengo los siguientes archivos del FRONT-END

```
/www/index.html
/www/jp/app.js
/www/dependencias/*.js
```

Todos estos archivos estarían comprimirlos dentro del JAR. Entonces cuando la aplicación JAR se ejecutaría, verifica que los archivos no se encuentran, el no existir los crea ella misma. De forma que el transporte programa sea sencillo, un vez que se ejecute, aparezcan los archivos en el mismo directorio donde se ejecuta.
Es posible?

Comment: ¿como se despliega la aplicación? ¿usas un servidor de aplicación o tu aplicación implementa el suyo propio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Su idea es interesante y existen varias formas para implementarla.

Si yo tuviera este problema y siempre que no sean muchos ficheros, no extraería los recursos del jar, sino que los serviría directamente desde dentro del jar  y los enviaría en las respuestas a las peticiones.

También puede extraer los recursos a una carpeta temporal donde la aplicación tenga permisos de escritura, preferentemente en una localización temporal dentro del perfil del usuario que ejecuta la aplicación. Puede implementar una clase que recupere los recursos contenidos y los escriba al disco:

```
CodeSource fuente = MiClase.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
if (fuente != null) {
  URL urlJar = fuente.getLocation();
  ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(urlJar.openStream());
  while(true) {
    ZipEntry recurso = zip.getNextEntry();
    if (recurso == null)
      break; //Fin de iteracion dentro del jar
    String name = recurso.getName();
    if (/*Filtrar los recursos aqui*/...) {
      /* Si es un recurso, copiarlo a la carpeta destino */
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: voy a trabajar en esto ! gracias